# Higher Class Hierarchy vs Wider Class Spectrum

Tags: design-patterns, adapter, class-hierarchy

I have a "Good Practice" Question:

**Lets assume a case where one have many List Types**

1. IObservableList      With Events
2. IReadOnlyList        Read Only
3. ISomeList            Some List that perform additional operations

**Is it better to define 6 classes Like**

1. ObservableList:IList
2. ObservableReadonlyList:IList
3. ObservableSomeList:IList
4. ReadonlyList:IList
5. ReadonlySomeList:IList
6. ObservableReadonlySomeList:IList

**or**

**Adapting one too another using 3 Classes:**

1. ReadOnlyListAdapter : IList
2. ObservableListAdapter : IList
3. SomeListAdapter : IList

**and instanciating with**

IList MyObservableReadonlySomeList = new ReadonlyListAdapter(new ObservableListAdapter(new SomeListAdapter)));

**Note:**

i tend to like the 6 classes better, but what goes when there are 6 or 7 properties for a class???
30-50 classes?

Thank you, have a nice day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i tend to like the 6 classes better, but what goes when there are 6 or
>   7 properties for a class??? 30-50 classes?

You might want to look at the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern.  It may indeed be what you're actually doing with what you're calling adapters.

Comment: Ya It is kind of similar, though i wonder about protected members...
how does the DecoratorConcrete access these? or it has to be a sub-class of the concrete component?